# Allow access to php file only if redirected

Tags: php

Is it possible to disallow direct access to a PHP file and allow the access only if it's redirected from other PHP file?

For example, access to `loading.php` should be only allowed if it's redirected from `example.php` page. How how can I do that?

I hope you understand what I mean.  If not, please ask me, and I will try to explain better.

Comment: http is stateless, however sessions are often used for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check referer, but it not secure:

**loading.php**

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!=='http://yoursite/example.php')
  die('Denied');
```

--

or you can set visited flag in session

**example.php**

```
<?php
  $_SESSION['isVisitedExample'] = true;
```

**loading.php**

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_SESSION['isVisitedExample']))
    die('Denied');
```

--

or in cookie (not secure)

**example.php**

```
<?php
  setcookie('isVisitedExample', 1);
```

**loading.php**

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_COOKIE['isVisitedExample']))
    die('Denied');
```

--

or mix this methods

Answer (score 2):

example.php

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['loading']='yes';
```

loading.php

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['loading']=='yes'){
/all good
}else{
//bad, redirect back or whatever
}
$_SESSION['loading']=''; // clear session var
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!

btw, you forgot to add ) to your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Test for the variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. (yes, the incorrect spelling is what must be used.) That variable contains the URL of the site that a user came from. The `REFERER` header is blank or '-' if the page is accessed directly.

The code for this would look something like the following:

```
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) or $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == '-') {
  exit; // do nothing if hit directly.
}
// The real page logic goes here.
```

If you want to only allow the loading page from a specific URL, then you may test for that URL instead of testing for `empty()`.

Please be aware that the `REFERER` header is sent by the browser and easily spoofed. That said, checking the referer header is useful for blocking other sites from directly loading images from your site.

Another option would be to use sessions and session variables to check that someone hit the appropriate page before the loader page.

Comment: never use `$_SERVER['REFERER']` its browser set

Comment: It's actually HTTP_REFERER, not REFERER.

Comment: still such as a bad idea it shoudn't even be mentioned.